TextArea not clickable inside draggable div
I am using Drag and drop functionality for divs. All divs has a common html structure based on dynamic data.
Each div has one textarea in which I am adding description for each item.
Before I implemented drag and drop, I was able to edit text inside textarea. But now i am not.
If I remove the drag and drop functionality, everything is working fine.
I have added one icon which will show-hide the textarea if user wants to edit the description text. may be it's happening because of that?
How can I resolve this so I can edit text within textarea inside the drag and drop div?

